# ASP.NET horizontal navigation menu implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm a c# application developer working on my first ASP project. The ASP.NET project I've inherited uses a standard horizontal navigation menu toward the top of the site for navigation. Items on the navigation menu change depending on what permission the logged in user has. Currently, to do this, the ASP c# code adds javascript code to the main page that calls methods in the "sothink" javascript library that adds the menu items to the "sothink" navigation menu.

My questions are:

1) Why would someone use javascript to implement a navigation menu in an ASP.NET application if ASP provides the libraries to do this already?

2) Is a javascript menu snappier/smoother than an ASP menu implementation?

3) Is it not as easy to have permission dependent menu item implemented with ASP as opposed to javascript?

3) If one were to build an ASP menu, would that get broken down into javascript for the client side?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It's a matter of what you are trying to accomplish. If you have a static menu, then just build it in HTML. If you have a dynamic, role-based menu, then you should build it on the server-side since that controls your roles & authentication. In the end, it's just HTML to the client. And maybe some javascript/css to make things move around.

Those ASP.NET libraries you are referring to are just ways for you to deliver HTML/javascript to the browser easily through code-behind methods. It's nothing you can't just do with vanilla javascript and HTML... because that is what is given to the client in the end.

2) It's the same thing. ASP.NET menu gets rendered as HTML/javascript. It's just a way for you to control it easily from code-behind *before* it is rendered to the client. That being said, those controls are only going to do so much. If you really want to customize your menu's functionality on the client-side, you may need custom JS on top of a server control.

3) Permissions are controlled through your server-side logic. As such... this should be done in ASP.NET code-behind.

3) Yes (and HTML).

ASP.NET server controls give you easy access to dynamically configure elements of the page *before* it is rendered to the client. Once the page is delivered, ASP.NET is done (ignoring any AJAX-type functionality). Javascript/css have to take over to control the menu (whether you generated the JS or some server control did it for you).

So I think you've probably noticed that the menu system was potentially built incorrectly... the server should just deliver the correct menu items to the client based on their permissions. It shouldn't deliver a generic menu and then custom javascript to modify the menu... that just is extra work... and confusing.